# iOS switch view in a navigation controller from the app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to switch to another view in my navigation controller when the application `didRecieveRemoteNotification` is triggered.

Here is my current code:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    ConvViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chatConversation"];
    [(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:ivc animated:NO];
```

For some reason i get `(lldb)` error on the second line.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit**

I'm using storyboard segue identifier: `chatConv` 
to my Custom Class: `ConvViewController` and my custom class has a Storyboard ID: `chatConversation`

Here is my Storyboard:
[image]

Comment: what is the exactly error message you receive?

Comment: It only says `(lldb)`

Comment: Is the navigation controller you show the root view controller of the window? It doesn't look like it from your image. In any case, you should log both ivc and self.window.rootViewController to see what they show.

Answer (score 0):

chatConversation should be a ViewController in MainStoryboard.storyboard.  In MainStoryboard.storyboard, select your chatConversation ViewController.  In the Identities panel, make sure your custom class is set to ChatViewController.

Answer (score 0):

instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier takes a view controller identifier not a segue identifier.  So something like:

```
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"convViewController"];
```